# CryptoJS encrypts AES with passphrase but PHP decrypt needs a key

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I am using [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES) to encrypt a string:

```
  function doHash(msg){
    msg = String(msg);
    var passphrase = 'aggourakia';
    var hash = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, passphrase);
    var ciphertext=  hash.ciphertext.toString(); //return ciphertext instead of object
    return ciphertext;      
}
```

As I understand it, [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES) *uses the passphrase to generate a key*, which is then used to encrypt the data.

> However I'd like to decrypt the cipher using a PHP function, or maybe
>   an online tool such as this: http://aesencryption.net/

The issue is that these expect a **key**, **not a passphrase.**

How can I supply directly a **key** to the CryptoJS AES, which I can use on the server-side or any online tool to decrypt?

The thing is, I already have a really hard time finding PHP functions to decrypt AES ciphers already, and this passphrase/key thing is adding to the complexity

Comment: I'd bet that the passphrase is used to derive a key via PBKDF2.

Comment: @Narf How much are you willing to bet?

Comment: @owlstead Hehe, it's just a guess.

Comment: @Narf Looks like somebody [didn't want to bet on it :)](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19739/does-googles-crypto-js-aes-encryption-use-pbkdf2-as-default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to supply the **key** directly you should supply **IV** too. The IV (initialization vector) is needed so it can be XOR'ed with the 1st block of the message. Then the ciphertext of the first block is XOR'ed  with the 2nd block of the message and so on. This is called [cipher-block chaining (CBC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29).

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

This is from CryptoJS docs https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Custom_Key_and_IV

You can generate keys and IVs with **PBKDF2** like @Narf wrote. https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#PBKDF2

About PHP: [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) has MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 cipher which is AES 128. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192 and MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 are not compatible with AES 192 and AES 256 because AES uses 128 bit block with all key sizes. Rijndael's has a configurable block size. CryptoJS will use 128bit AES if you supply a 128 bit key it will use 256 bit if you use the function that accepts a passphrase.

Comment: If you ask me mcrypt is obsolete but not deprecated :( I had some mail from a dev that they want to create a new release of the underlying C library, but it would be the first one in years - currently it is not maintained (so if there are bugs or vulnerabilities, nobody will fix them).

Comment: Your main point that you should supply an IV to use the `encrypt` function that uses a key is correct, so I've fixed the mistakes I could find. Please review the changes and take heed.

Comment: Do I need to use the IV in the PHP function too? I haven't spun up a PHP server just yet - so I'm using this tool to see if it will work in mCrypt - http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/ - this is an mCrypt tool actually. Unfortunately all I see is that I need to type here the ciphertext and the key to decrypt. I am copying the key you gave in your example and the outputted ciphertext from your example, but it seems to be sputting out gibberish

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides yes you need the IV for PHP too.