# AES encryption with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to do AES encryption with AngularJS. 
first, I have tried to do AES encryption on this site: http://aesencryption.net/

I am getting right answer, which is: `YH5im+aMmPX+8YyNBeaR+A==`

As I want to do it with angular, I have applied this solution:
https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography

This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ionic', 'mdo-angular-cryptography','base64']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$crypto','$base64', function($scope, $crypto,$base64) {

    //var eee = $base64.encode('35681448');
    //console.log(eee);
    //var ee1 = $base64.encode('3568144800000000');

    var enc = $crypto.encrypt('12345678', '1234567800000000');
    console.log(enc);

   // var dec = $crypto.decrypt(enc,'1234567800000000')

    var kkk = $base64.encode(enc);
    console.log(kkk);

    //console.log(dec);
    //var decrypted = $crypto.decrypt(encrypted, 'some other custom key');
}]);
```

The answer which I get in browser console is:

- `U2FsdGVkX1+4anXDu6zJGHmUpCPoIfobUk5A18upVNQ=`
- `VTJGc2RHVmtYMSs0YW5YRHU2ekpHSG1VcENQb0lmb2JVazVBMTh1cFZOUT0=`

The answer I am getting is different. I want the same answer which i am getting on first aes encryption site.

How can I do 128-bit AES encryption with AngularJS?

Comment: Those two are inherently incompatible (EVP_BytesToKey vs. direct key usage). You will have to decide which one is more important. Either you change the online encryption calculator or the library. Anyway, why do you want to have compatible encryption with a site, whose encryption is obsolete. Unauthenticated encryption is most likely not what you want.

Comment: actually, I am calling an API, which accepts the only encryption, which i am getting as a output in that AES site.(http://aesencryption.net/).So, i have to use that method only with angularjs.

Comment: If the API is fixed and cannot be changed, then you have to use another library. CryptoJS will be capable of doing what you're trying to do. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26488127/1816580